# ActiveRecord constructs incorrect SQL when using JSONB/Hash with Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, jsonb

I am using `jsonb` datatype for a column named `data`. When I query using a simple hash, it works correctly:

```
[1] pry(PredictionService)> Prediction.where(data: {"innings_no" => 1})

  Prediction Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "predictions".* FROM "predictions" WHERE "data"."innings_no" = 1
=> #<Prediction::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fcb34634e78>
```

It fails with an incorrect SQL when I use an array like this:

```
[2] pry(PredictionService)> Prediction.where(data: {"innings_no" => [1,2]})

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "data" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"data"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"data"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
from /Users/lenin.rajasekaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@duggout-app/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
```

Is this a known issue with jsonb/ActiveRecord or this can be fixed?

I cannot use Postgres's array functions to access a particular key, as the  keys are dynamic and I am using this query to find existing records before creating a new one.

Comment: Are you sure that first one works? Sure as in "I did `Prediction.where(data: {"innings_no" => 1}).to_a` and it gave me the expected results" sure?

Comment: Yes, I can show a GIF screencap

Comment: I think you are right, Rails think `data` is a table name and `innings_no` is a column in that table. I thought it is working because I saw a valid `#<Prediction::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fcb34634e78>` result

Comment: So what does `data` look like? Is it a JSON array, object, something else?

Comment: It is a `Hash` object. ActiveRecord accepts `Hash` for the `data` column while in `create` method. But does not accept the same when using it in `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a `jsonb` column called `data` that contains things like

```
{ "innings_no": 6, ... }
```

To work with that column in a query, you have to use the [PostgreSQL JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). In this case, you probably want `->>`, which extracts a field as a `text` value, and a type cast. So something like:

```
Prediction.where("(data ->> 'innings_no')::int = ?", 1)
```

The `data ->> 'innings_no'` is more or less equivalent to `data['innings_no']` in Ruby (or JavaScript for that matter), the `::int` casts the string that `->>` yields to an integer.

Of course, using `=` inside a little SQL snippet means that you're responsible for modifying the query to account for an array:

```
Prediction.where("(data ->> 'innings_no')::int = any(array[?])", [1,2])
```

or:

```
Prediction.where("(data ->> 'innings_no')::int in (?)", [1,2])
```

Luckily the `= any` and `in` versions will work in either case so you can do this and no worry about

```
innings = 1
Prediction.where("(data ->> 'innings_no')::int = any(array[?])", innings)

innings = [1,2]
Prediction.where("(data ->> 'innings_no')::int = any(array[?])", innings)
```

---

If, on the other hand, you have a Ruby Hash has you want to find models whose `data` overlaps that Hash then you can use the `@>` operator:

> `@> jsonb`
>   Does the left JSON value contain the right JSON path/value entries at the top level?
>   `'{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb @> '{"b":2}'::jsonb`

and a `to_json` call to build the right hand side. For example:

```
hash = { :innings_no => 1, :pancakes => 11 }
Prediction.where('data @> ?', hash.to_json)
```

PostgreSQL will automatically cast the `?` string to JSONB for you but you could be explicit and say:

```
Prediction.where('data @> ?::jsonb', hash.to_json)
# -------------------------^^^^^^^
```

---

Your first query:

```
Prediction.where(data: {"innings_no" => 1})
```

doesn't work because ActiveRecord reserves that argument structure for referencing JOINed tables as you can see in the SQL:

```
WHERE "data"."innings_no" = 1
table -^^^^
column -------^^^^^^^^^^
```

so when that ends up in the database, PostgreSQL will be looking for a table called `data` but won't find one. Of course, this won't fail until it hits that database so it looked fine in `pry`.

Your second query:

```
Prediction.where(data: {"innings_no" => [1,2]})
```

fails for the same reason but it fails earlier because, for some reason, the `[1,2]` array makes ActiveRecord want to know the structure of the `data` table while it is trying to build the query; the odd looking query on the `pg_attribute` and `pg_attrdef` system tables is what ActiveRecord uses to figure out the structure of a table so any time you see a query like that it is ActiveRecord trying to figure out the columns structure of a table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way to compare my Hash with the existing `data` without looking up individual keys? Thought it could be possible to extract the keys one by one and build a Postgres JSON query to find a match, I would like to do a dumb comparison of `=` like we do for other regular columns like `varchar`. Can we convert the whole `data` to `varchar` and our Ruby Hash to `string` and do a `=` comparison?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for PostgreSQL's `@>` operator as in my update.